# "-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data" not called

Tags: iphone, web-services, iphone-sdk-3.0, soap

Have a look to this code snippet:-

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{               
    [webData setLength: 0];           
}



-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{
    NSLog(@"Recieving Data...");
    [webData appendData:data];

}



-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSLog(theXML);


}
```

I am calling a SOAP web service.There are no errors or warnings displayed in my code.
When I hit the web service through safari it works fine. But the problem arises when I try
hit it through my codes.
Everything works fine but the `connection:didRecieveData` does not gets called.
Thus, I get no data in the `webData` variable. This `webData` is a `NSMutableData` object.
The problem seems to be silly but any one with any answers ....

Thank You All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are having a memory management issue. I could be mistaken on this, but I believe that even:

```
NSURLConnection* connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

won't work, because `connection` will be released at the end of the containing method, when `connection` goes out of scope. Make sure `NSURLConnection *connection` and `NSMutableData *data` are declared as **member variables** where ever you are doing this, and that you `alloc` and `init` them appropriately. My code usually looks like:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:30.0];
    // cancel any old connection
    if(connection) {
        [connection cancel];
        [connection release];
    }
    // create new connection and begin loading data
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection) {
        // if the connection was created correctly, release old data (if any), and alloc new
        [data release];
        data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

Also, `release` the connection and data in `dealloc`. For good measure, `release` and set them to `nil` at the very end of `didFailWithError` and `didFinishLoading`:

```
[connection release];
connection = nil;
[data release];
data = nil;
```

Good luck; I've done this a million times, let me know if you cannot get it working.

Comment: Thanks Mickey,

But I still have the same issue, its not working. I tested the URL in my browser, its loading there. Can you please help me please?

Comment: Nothing will be release just because a variable pointing to it got out of scoop !  The connection object don't need to be retained and should be release in the delegate's callback after it has finnish its job.

Answer (score 2):

You don't happen to be calling the NSConnection in a thread do you? If you are then what's happening is that the thread is terminating before NSConnection and its delegates have finished so it'll just bomb out without an error.

A workaround for this is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216304/nsurlconnection-delegation-and-threading-iphone/1216371#1216371) thread

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any error messages in `didFailWithError` either? Kind of a silly suggestion, but are you sure you're setting the proper `NSURLConnection` delegate?

```
NSURLConnection* connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Sometimes it's something small like that.

Another idea is to drop in a toolkit like `ASIHTTPRequest` and see if it works going through them.

Answer (score 0):

There also could be problems, if are trying to start NSURLConnection from another Thread.
Please call method [connection start] on main thread, if you have not customized Run Loop for it.