# HTTP POST request not working, delegate methods are not being called

Tags: iphone, http, nsurlconnection

I’m wondering why this HTTP POST request isn’t working in my iPhone app.

I know for a fact that the URL is correct and that the variables I’m sending are correct, but for some reason the request is not being received by the `.aspx` page.

**EDIT:**

I refactored the code into its own class, with its own delegate methods. But the delegate methods are not being called.

The class is called like this:

```
URLCallClass *reporter=[[[URLCallClass alloc] init]autorelease];
    [reporter sendoview:@"http://mysite/page.aspx" params:httpBodyString];
```

and this is the actual class itself:

```
-(void)sendview:(NSString *)server params:(NSString *)params
{

    NSURL* url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:server];   
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [url release];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    connectionResponse=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
    //NSURLConnection *connectionResponse = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];


    if (!connectionResponse)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"---------Report  Request submitted ---------");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"report received response");

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"report failed with error");
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Promo View Reported");
}

-(void)dealloc

{
    [connectionResponse release];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns it had to do with threading

[NSURLConnection delegation and threading - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216304/nsurlconnection-delegation-and-threading-iphone)

I used this solution

http://www.depl0y.com/?p=345

Comment: So to clarify:  all of this code was running on a thread other than the main thread?

Comment: Well there was  UIView Running on the main thread and the httprequest code was in an instance of class in this UIView. I believe this http request class exited before completing its async urlconnection once the parent UIView function that called it finished executing the method that called it.

So I dont think it was on the main thread but the class that called it was.

I could be way off here though, this is quite new to me and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the connection:didFailWithError: in the delegate.

`NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);` will show you, what exactly went wrong.

Comment: the didfailWithError handler never gets called

Answer (score 0):

Is your `url` actually being created? If there is any problem NSURLs `initWithString:` method will return `nil`.

Comment: I commented out all of my code except for the code in question and it worked find. I use another NSURLConnection in the same class. It gets executed before this one. Could that be causing the problem somehow?

Comment: url is being successfully created

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing the response headers? I would suggest that you implement almost every delegate method to check what is actually happening with your connection, try first printing  the didReceiveResponse Method, and some of the data you're receiving using the connection:didReceiveData method.

And perhaps the encoding of your data is something the server cannot process, try using **NSUTF8StringEncoding** instead of NSISOLatin1StringEncoding as the body encoding.